# Laravel how to assign model id to 0 or null if no results are found for a model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

From a zip code I look up the county. I have more zips than counties, so for some zip codes I will not have a county. I am then trying to put an id for the returned county into an address, however county can be null:

```
$zip = ZipCode::all()->random(1);
$state = $zip->state();
$county = $zip->county();
```

then try to assign $county->id in address will fail due to county being null

```
return [
        'address1' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'address2' => '',
        'city' => $faker->city,
        'state' => $state->name,
        'zip' => $zip->zip_code,
        'country' => $zip->country,
        'state_id' => $state->id,
        'county_id' => $county->id,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'fax' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'comments' => $faker->sentence(),
        'active' => 1
    ];
```

In ZipCode Model

```
public function state()
{
    return State::where('short_name', $this->state)->firstOrFail();
}
public function county()
{
    $county = County::where('name', $this->county)->first();
    if($county === null)
    {
        //what to do here to be able to access $county->id?
        return new County(); // looks like it works...but weird?
    }
    return $county;
}
```

If I do return a new County model I can get access to $county->id,

Is this how I should go about assigning an id's when there is no matching data?  Or should I do something else that I am missing?